# batch file to run command on folder and sub-folders with specific name

Tags: windows, batch-file, permissions

i need to run a command

```
icacls "foldername" /deny IUSR:(OI)(CI)(X)
```

on every folder with name "UploadFiles" or "Newsletter" or "somethingelse" in a c:\inetpub\wwwroot

i used the dir command to extract all folders and then run a long batch file for each "row" (folder)

like that

```
icacls "folder1/UploadFiles" /deny IUSR:(OI)(CI)(X)
icacls "folder2/UploadFiles" /deny IUSR:(OI)(CI)(X)
icacls "folder3/Newsletter" /deny IUSR:(OI)(CI)(X)
icacls "folder4/ssss/Newsletter" /deny IUSR:(OI)(CI)(X)
```

how can i use the for command to do the same work?

Comment: How many matches do you have? You show 3 for now. is that the basic criteria to match?

Comment: for now it is just "UploadFiles" or "Newsletter" or "somethingelse"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do create a variable with all your match criteria, then run a for loop for each match:

```
@echo off
set "vars="*UploadFiles*" "*Newsletter*" "*somethingelse*""
for /D %%i in (%vars%) do icacls "%%~i" /deny IUSR:(OI)(CI)(X)
```

This way you can update the `%vars%` variable with relevant search criteria.

Comment: how it iterate over all the folders the folders?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking? This will iterate through all the local folders where the script is running. if it finds matches, it will perform the task.

Comment: i think that it's run on the var, i need it to run all over the folders and if the folder name is has one of the vars then to do the command

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what this does. Have you tested it?

Comment: it don't do nothing, i try to echo the folder name and nothing

Comment: Then there are not any folders in the root of the script where you are running it

Comment: oh, you marked the question as correct, does that mean it now worked?

Comment: tnx. when i run it for each "foldename" it's work
FOR /D /r %%G in ("uploadfiles*") do icacls "%%G" /deny IUSR:(OI)(CI)(X)